# Mostrar imagen de una ruta dinámica en FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Mostrar una imagen a partir de una ruta dinámica en función al id del registro de mi base con la librería FPDF

```
session_start();
$id_user = $_SESSION ['usuario']['id_user'];
$query = $con -> query ("SELECT id_inspirador, id_user FROM inspirador WHERE id_user = '".$id_user."'");
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $id_inspirador = $row['id_inspirador'];

                $path = "../../files/inspirador/avatar/".$id_inspirador;
                if(file_exists($path)){
                  $directorio = opendir($path);
                  while($archivo = readdir($directorio))
                  {
                    if(!is_dir($archivo)){

                      //en html uso esto y funciona bien echo "<img src='../../files/inspirador/avatar/$id_inspirador/$archivo' class='header-img' />";


                      $pdf->Image('../../files/inspirador/avatar/$id_inspirador/$archivo' , 42 ,268, 122 , 30,'JPG');
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

**Me da el siguiente error**

> Warning:
>   getimagesize(../../files/inspirador/avatar/$id_inspirador/$archivo):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina\lib\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 1202 FPDF error:
>   Missing or incorrect image file:
>   ../../files/inspirador/avatar/$id_inspirador/$archivo

Comment: intenta cambiando las comillas simples por dobles :D

Comment: Debes comprobar si la ruta esta bien es la correcta